# Why is my code red in my GitHub repo and how to disable it?

Tags: json, github

My code is syntactically correct and works perfectly fine.

So why is the linter flagging it red?

It's annoying and I don't like the way it looks.

It's a `.json` file.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> My code is syntactically correct

No it's not: [JSON doesn't permit comments](https://web.archive.org/web/20190308024153/https://plus.google.com/+DouglasCrockfordEsq/posts/RK8qyGVaGSr).

A workaround is to use a [Linguist override](https://github.com/github/linguist#overrides) by adding a [`.gitattributes` file](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) with the following content:

```
*.json linguist-language=JavaScript
```

This tells GitHub to treat `.json` files in your repository as full JavaScript (which, of course, permits comments) instead of JSON.

GitHub [appears to cache Linguist highlighting data](https://github.com/github/linguist/issues/1792#issuecomment-286420414), so any existing JSON files may need to be modified, committed, and pushed again before the new highlighting shows up.